# How can create a count down timer for user input?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I am wanting to create a program that allows for a limited time for user input. I want the countdown timer that continuously gets updated; while asking for user input on a different line. Currently, the countdown timer is printing to the same line as the user input line. How can I get them on separate lines? Or how do I cancel out user input after a specific time?

```
def showTime():
  h = 0
  m = 1
  s = 0

  total_seconds = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

  while total_seconds > 0:
    timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds=total_seconds)

      print(timer, end="\r")

      time.sleep(5)

      total_seconds -= 5
  print("Out of time")


def main():

  p = Process(target=showTime)
  p.start()
  user_input = input('\nPlease enter your answer: ')
  if user_input == A:
    p.terminate()
    print('Correct')
  else:
    p.terminate()
    print('Incorrect')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TalhaTayyab sorry updated my question for calification.

Comment: Using two processes will lead to them fighting over control of the terminal. You will probably have to use a more low-level library like `curses` instead of using `input`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to check that out.